# Long running GC in Application

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I am currently running an application which requires a maximum heap size of 4GB in 8GB RAM.

Currently I use the following flags to handle garbage collection.

> NS_PARAMS="-Xms4096M -Xmx4096M -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -verbose:gc  -Xloggc:../logs/gc.txt -XX:SurvivorRatio=12 -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled    -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=16  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:MetaspaceSize=700M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=700M -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=128M -XX:NewSize=512M -XX:MaxNewSize=512M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=$HEAP_DUMP_PATH -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=65"

G1 Old Generation Garbage Collection time is 55 sec in 1 minute.

Any advice on what I should change in order to reduce these long pauses would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An exert from my garbage collection logs can be found https://pastebin.com/raw/Mhhb4Dj0

Comment: Start with removing all options you don’t understand.

Comment: @AnatolyG the string deduplication is only applied to strings which survive long enough to get to the old generation. That’s normally not a problem—unless someone messes around with the survivor rates or the size of the New generation, of course. That doesn’t preclude that some applications might run better without…